# Why somebody call "EMCA-262 Edition 6" as "ECMAScript 2015"

Tags: ecmascript-6

I heard somebody call "EMCA-262 Edition 6" as "ECMAScript 2015".  Is the "ECMAScript 2015" now official name for "EMCA-262 Edition 6"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think that it's the official name given by ECMA. There are speculations that it may be referred to as ECMAScript 2015, but nothing has been confirmed officially as of now.

You can check more of the discussion going on at [esdiscuss.org](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/javascript-2015) on this.

### EDIT

As commented correctly by kangax, on 17 March 2015, the “EMCA-262 Edition 6” is now officially named as **“ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification”**.

Check the [link](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts)

Comment: Actually, yes, it is an official name now (no matter how silly it sounds) — http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts See the front page of latest spec

Comment: I saw the official name here; http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html